# In R, the data.frame name `iris`, how can i know which package it come from?

Tags: r

I know the data.frame name `iris`, how can i know which package it come from ?
is there any code or function for detecting the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find this out programmatically you may use `find` function.

```
find('iris')
#[1] "package:datasets"
```

remove `'package:'` to get the name of the package.

```
sub('package:', '', find('iris'), fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "datasets"
```

`find` function also works with functions.

```
find('sqrt')
#[1] "package:base"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could get this

```
dat <- as.data.frame(data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))$results)
dat[dat$Item=="iris", c(1,3,4)]
```

output:

```
      Package Item                       Title
99   datasets iris  Edgar Anderson's Iris Data
1178   locfit iris Fisher's Iris Data (subset)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is available from `?iris` - `?` leads you to the documentation, where you will see the package name